# Can't insert value to table using PDO & MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have this php function which encrypts the password provided by a form to this: 
`0xb539dbae17ef3d7c49d0f6f63ba18787` .

```
function encrypt($str) {
$key = array();
$dst = array();
$i = 0;

$nBytes = strlen($str);
        while ($i < $nBytes){
             $i++;
                $key[$i] = ord(substr($str, $i - 1, 1));
                $dst[$i] = $key[$i];
}  

$rslt = $key[1] + $key[2]*256 + $key[3]*65536 + $key[4]*16777216;
$one = $rslt * 213119 + 2529077;
$one = $one - intval($one/ 4294967296) * 4294967296;

$rslt = $key[5] + $key[6]*256 + $key[7]*65536 + $key[8]*16777216;
$two = $rslt * 213247 + 2529089;
$two = $two - intval($two/ 4294967296) * 4294967296;

$rslt = $key[9] + $key[10]*256 + $key[11]*65536 + $key[12]*16777216;
$three = $rslt * 213203 + 2529589;
$three = $three - intval($three/ 4294967296) * 4294967296;

$rslt = $key[13] + $key[14]*256 + $key[15]*65536 + $key[16]*16777216;
$four = $rslt * 213821 + 2529997;
$four = $four - intval($four/ 4294967296) * 4294967296;

$key[4] = intval($one/16777216);        
$key[3] = intval(($one - $key[4] * 16777216) / 65535);
$key[2] = intval(($one - $key[4] * 16777216 - $key[3] * 65536) / 256);
$key[1] = intval(($one - $key[4] * 16777216 - $key[3] * 65536 - $key[2] * 256));

$key[8] = intval($two/16777216);     
$key[7] = intval(($two - $key[8] * 16777216) / 65535);
$key[6] = intval(($two - $key[8] * 16777216 - $key[7] * 65536) / 256);
$key[5] = intval(($two - $key[8] * 16777216 - $key[7] * 65536 - $key[6] * 256));

$key[12] = intval($three/16777216);     
$key[11] = intval(($three - $key[12] * 16777216) / 65535);
$key[10] = intval(($three - $key[12] * 16777216 - $key[11] * 65536) / 256);
$key[9] = intval(($three - $key[12] * 16777216 - $key[11] * 65536 - $key[10] * 256));

$key[16] = intval($four/16777216);     
$key[15] = intval(($four - $key[16] * 16777216) / 65535);
$key[14] = intval(($four - $key[16] * 16777216 - $key[15] * 65536) / 256);
$key[13] = intval(($four - $key[16] * 16777216 - $key[15] * 65536 - $key[14] * 256));

$dst[1] = $dst[1] ^ $key[1];

$i=1;
while ($i<16){
    $i++;
    $dst[$i] = $dst[$i] ^ $dst[$i-1] ^ $key[$i];
}

$i=0;
while ($i<16){
    $i++;
    if ($dst[$i] == 0) {
        $dst[$i] = 102;
    }
}

$encrypt = "0x";
$i=0;
while ($i<16){
    $i++;
    if ($dst[$i] < 16) {
        $encrypt = $encrypt . "0" . dechex($dst[$i]);
    } else {
        $encrypt = $encrypt . dechex($dst[$i]);
    }
}

return $encrypt;
}
```

The column in database is `[password] [binary] (16) NOT NULL`

the query is this:

```
$query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO user_auth (account,password) VALUES (?, ?) ");
$query->bindValue(1, $accname);
$query->bindValue(2, $password);
try{
$query->execute(); 
.................
```

But it returns: Implicit conversion from data type varchar to binary is not allowed. When i use `mssql_query` the insert is executed w/o problems. Have tried the `CONVERT(binary)` but the data isn't readable from the program which uses them. Also tried to change the column to varchar but ssame happened. Maybe I'm doing smth wrong with the PDO statement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Holy moly, that is some loopless code.

Comment: Try `->bindValue(2, $password, PDO::PARAM_LOB)` for it to a binary type. MySQL can't differentiate between human-readable "strings" and binary "garbage" - it's all just strings to MySQL.

Comment: I am getting the same message. `General error: 10007 Implicit conversion from data type varchar to binary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query. [10007] (severity 5) [(null)]`

Comment: if I do this which is working `$query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO user_auth (account,password) VALUES (?, $password) ");` I'm open to sql injection right?